# Dropdown using css and javascript not working when internal css position is swapped

Tags: javascript, css

**This works**

```
 .c1
  {
  background-color:red;
   position:relative;
  }
  .c2
  {
  background-color:blue;
  position:absolute;
  height:50px;
  width:100px;
   display:none;}

.show
{
 display:block;
 }

<body>
<button  class="c1" onclick="myfunction()">click</button>
<div id="change" class="c2">drop </div>

<script>
function myfunction(){
document.getElementById("change").classList.toggle("show")
}
 </script>
```

**but swap .show and .c2,It will not work.**

```
.c1
{
background-color:red;
position:relative;
}
  .show
{
 display:block;
 }

 .c2
{
background-color:blue;
position:absolute;
height:50px;
width:100px;
display:none;}



<body>
<button  class="c1" onclick="myfunction()">click</button>
<div id="change" class="c2">drop </div>

<script>
function myfunction(){
document.getElementById("change").classList.toggle("show")
}
 </script>
```

It might be because of classList.toggle which i have used.
It changes display of division from none to block.
only code change is the .c2 class and .show class position. 
Does it matter in which order the css classes are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it looks strange it first sight, but it is actually quite logical if you think of how css orders the declarations, which is called specificity. For every front-end developer it would be good to at least once read the excellent and extensive [guide at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

From the guide:

> Specificity is the means by which browsers decide which CSS property values are the most relevant to an element and, therefore, will be applied. Specificity is based on the matching rules which are composed of CSS selectors of different sorts.

For example, declarations further down the bottom of your document have a higher precedence, and these will applied. For example if you have the declarations below, your background will be blue.

```
body { background: red; }
...
body { background: blue; }
```

But the more specific you are, the more important it is, and the more specific declaration will be applied. So althought a bit counterintuitive at first, with the code below your background will actually be red:

```
html body { background: red; }
...
body { background: blue; }
```

Back to your example: an element with class `.show` should be displayed as a block element, but if you have the declaration of that class *before* the declaration of another class which is applied to the same element (`.c2` in this case), it will get overridden. You can however override that by being more specific:

```
.c2.show { display: block; }
.c2 { display: none; }

<div class="c2"><!-- This element is hidden --></div>
<div class="c2 show"><!-- This element is shown --></div>
```

You should try to avoid `!important` whenever possible, as it can make it unclear sometimes why a css declaration is applied, and it's more difficult to override it. And basically, it's almost never necessary.

Comment: nah, you souldn't use w3schools... they have good seo, but are mistaken sometimes and almost never complete. You can better use MDN as a reference, and sites like csstricks for examples and ideas

Answer (score 0):

`.show` and `.c2` have a conflicting `display` property. The browser takes into account the last value (top-down) it finds in the styles.

try

```
.show{
display:block!important;
}
```

and this will override the value of c2

Comment: Please don't use `!important`. Okay for a quick fix, but try to wrap around the code to avoid using it. Further read: http://james.padolsey.com/css/dont-use-important/

Comment: I've used !important a lot in production environments. Sometimes you don't have control over how CSS classes are combined, especially if you use JS UI libraries